# without pod installation how could get placepicker in swift

Tags: swift

I have already pod install but now i want to add one more pod 'GMSPlacePickerController' , In past I already change my project name so whenever i try to install pod then sometimes pod file not found, some times other error happen. So I just want google place picker without pod installion.

Comment: If not with pods, than you can do it manually. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

```
This guide shows how to manually add the GooglePlaces framework to your project and configure your build settings in Xcode.

1. Download the SDK source files:
 - GooglePlaces-2.5.0
 - GoogleMaps-2.5.0
 - GooglePlacePicker-2.5.0
 - GooglePlacePicker-2.5.0 is only needed if you are using the place picker.
2. Unpack the source files.
3. Launch Xcode and either open an existing project, or create a new project. If you're new to iOS, create a Single View Application, and disable Use Storyboards and enable Use Automatic Reference Counting.
4. Remove any Maps bundles from previous releases from your project.
5. Drag the following bundles into your project (when prompted, select Copy items if needed):
- GooglePlaces-2.5.0/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework
- GoogleMaps-2.5.0/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework

If you are using the place picker, drag the following bundles into your project (in addition to the previously listed bundles):

- GooglePlacePicker-2.5.0/Frameworks/GooglePlacePicker.framework
- GoogleMaps-2.5.0/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework
- GoogleMaps-2.5.0/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework

6. Right-click GooglePlaces.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder.
7. Drag the GooglePlaces.bundle from the Resources folder into your project. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.
8. If you are using the place picker, repeat the previous step and drag the GoogleMaps.bundle and GooglePlacePicker.bundle files into your project. These can be found in the GoogleMaps.framework and GooglePlacePicker.framework respectively.
9. Select your project from the Project Navigator, and choose your application's target.
10. Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:
 - GooglePlaces.framework
 - GoogleMapsBase.framework
 - GooglePlacePicker.framework (only if using the place picker)
 - GoogleMapsCore.framework (only if using the place picker)
 - GoogleMaps.framework (only if using the place picker)
 - Accelerate.framework
 - CoreData.framework
 - CoreGraphics.framework
 - CoreLocation.framework
 - CoreTelephony.framework
 - CoreText.framework
 - GLKit.framework
 - ImageIO.framework
 - libc++.tbd
 - libz.tbd
 - OpenGLES.framework
 - QuartzCore.framework
 - SystemConfiguration.framework
 -  UIKit.framework
11. Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the Build Settings tab.
12. In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC. If these settings are not visible, change the filter in the Build Settings bar from Basic to All.
```